# Why the for loop I made in this web scraping only print the first of the event? I hope it print all of the title, link, place, date and description

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm scraping this website but I have a problem after I run the codes where it only print the first events and the for loop is not iterating.

To append Events as List

```
class Events(object):
    def __init__(self, title=None,  place=None, date_posted=None, description=None, linkhref=None):
        self.title = title
        self.place = place
        self.date_posted = date_posted
        self.description = description
        self.linkhref = linkhref
```

I want to save it in CSV

```
sv_file = open('scrape2.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# Columns
csv_writer.writerow(['title', 'link', 'place', 'date_posted', 'description'])
```

In this part I want to scrape the website from 3 pages and find the details such as date, event name, venue and description of each events.

```
def scrape():

for page in range(0, 2):
    page = page + 1 
    base_url = 'https://allevents.in/malacca/all?ref=cityhome-popular' + str(page)

    source = requests.get(base_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

    all_event = soup.find_all('div', class_="event-list listview")
    events = []

    for item in all_event:

        title = item.find("h3").text.strip()

        link = item.find("h3")
        linkhref = link.find("a").get('href')   

        place = item.find("p", {"class":"location"}).text.strip()

        date_posted = item.find("div", {"class":"right"}).text.strip()

        description = item.find("p", {"class":"short-desc"}).text.strip()
        csv_writer.writerow([title, link, place, date_posted, description])
        events.append(Events(title, link, place, date_posted, description))
```

This is the for loop to iterate List

```
for event in events:
        print("Title: " + event.title)
        print("Link: " + event.linkhref)
        print("Place: " + str(event.place))
        print("Date: " + event.date_posted)
        print("Description: " + event.description)
        print("-----------------------------------")

    csv_file.close()

    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(scrape())
```

Comment: is this already display in list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch and write the results in different ways. Moreover, you can make use of namedtuple to shake off verbosity. Here is how I would do it.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple

class Events(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.base_url = 'https://allevents.in/malacca/all?ref=cityhome-popular'
        self.items = namedtuple('itemDocument', ['title','linkhref','place','date_posted','description'])

    def scrape(self):

        source = requests.get(self.base_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="event-item"):
            title = item.find("h3").text.strip()
            linkhref = item.find("h3").find("a").get('href')   
            place = ' '.join(item.find("p", {"class":"location"}).text.split())
            date_posted = item.find("div", {"class":"right"}).text.strip()
            description = item.find("p", {"class":"short-desc"}).text.strip()

            yield self.items(title,linkhref,place,date_posted,description)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    scraper = Events()
    with open("outputFile.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['title','linkhref','place','date_posted','description'])

        for item in scraper.scrape():
            writer.writerow([item.title,item.linkhref,item.place,item.date_posted,item.description])
```

Now, you can use the logic of traversing different pages within the above script as I've kicked out for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 'find' keyword only returns the first tagged element it finds. To return all the elements with specified tag such as "h3" I am not sure but it is "find_all" keyword. Do check it up first. And mark this answer as useful if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there; just change the middle section of your code, beginning of the assignment of `all_event`:

```
all_event = soup.find_all('h3')

events = []

for item in all_event:
    title = item.a.text
    linkhref = item.a['href']
    place = item.findNext('span').text.strip()
    date_posted = item.findNext('div', class_="right").text.strip()
    description = item.findNext('p', class_="short-desc").text.strip()
```

It should work from there, maybe with some modifications.